# React event bubbling without DOM nesting

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, dom-events

For context, `<NavTreeItem>` is a material-ui `<TreeItem>` and `<OpenDialogButton>` is a material-ui `<Button>`.

I have a component like this (simplified):

```js
function pushLink() {
  // ...
}

function openDialog(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
  // ...
}

<NavTreeItem onClick={pushLink}>
  <OpenDialogButton onClick={openDialog} />
  ...
  {dialogIsOpen && <Dialog />}
</NavTreeItem>
```

Let's say neither `openDialog()` nor `pushLink()` has been executed yet. If I click `<OpenDialogButton>` to open the dialog, it runs `openDialog()` which executes `event.stopPropagation()` so that the event doesn't bubble up to the tree item and executes `pushLink()` - just as expected. When `<Dialog>` is committed to the DOM, it is **not** nested within the `<NavTreeItem>` - just as expected. So far, only `openDialog()` has been executed.

But when I click on the `<Dialog>` element (or its backdrop), it executes `pushLink()` - undesirable behavior. It almost seems as if the click event is bubbling up to the `<NavTreeItem>` element - even though the `<Dialog>` element is not nested within it in the DOM. Why is this happening? How do I make it so that this doesn't occur?

Comment: My only guess is that this is React-specific behavior which propagates events if an element is nested within another _within JSX_, even if they aren't nested in the DOM.

Comment: If that's the case, then a simple solution would be to move `<Dialog>` out of `<NavTreeItem>`, but this isn't ideal for my situation.

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38619981/react-prevent-event-bubbling-in-nested-components-on-click

Comment: BTW if you figured it out, then please add the solution as an answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the solution I found:

```js
<NavTreeItem onClick={pushLink}>
  <OpenDialogButton onClick={openDialog} />
  ...
  <div onClick={(event) => event.stopPropagation()}>
    {dialogIsOpen && <Dialog />}
  </div>
</NavTreeItem>
```