# <i> tag icon in button causing event.target.value issues in react

Tags: reactjs

I am using a fontAwesome icon on a button and it seems that sometimes my code correctly uses the value of the button element and sometimes looks for the value of the icon (i tag element) when the button is clicked.  the following combination:

```
<button id="break-decrement" 
        value="-"
        onClick={this.handleBreakTime}>   <i class="fas fa-angle-double-down"></i> 
</button>

handleBreakTime() {
  let length = this.state.breakLen;
  let value = event.target.value;
  console.log(value);
  console.log(event.target.value);
  console.log(event.currentTarget.value);
}
```

logs this to the console when I don't click the icon:
"-"
"-"
undefined

but logs this when I do click the icon:
undefined
undefined
undefined

Is there a way to consistently get the value of the button when the icon is clicked on.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38619981/react-prevent-event-bubbling-in-nested-components-on-click

Comment: No, that addresses a situation where both elements have seperate onClick events.

Comment: I think there are answers there that help. Checking the event target might be a good plan.

Comment: Maybe you have to put onClick in <i> tag. But I’m not sure I can’t test it right now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
button > * {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

Comment: This is what worked.  I added it to the <i> tag like this:  <i pointerEvents="none"  and it stopped the icon from becoming the target.  Thank you!

Comment: Thanks, @JonathanPotter -- this solution worked for me. It also is more succinct than `onClick={e=> e.stopPropagation(); }`. Is there any convention or reason to choose one over the other, or just preference?

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass `event` as parameter in the `handleBreakTime` function.

Please have a look on this solution: [CodeSandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/naughty-smoke-ft1hq?file=/src/App.js)

Note: I have used functional based component just for simplicity. It'll work for both. Happy coding :)