# How to disable redirecting for some elements in an anchor tag?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, next.js

I have the following code :-

```
<a href="/">
 <h1>Hello Wolrd</h1>
 <p>This is some description</p>
 <div>....this is Image Carousel</div>
 <div class="dotButton>
   <button></button>
   <button></button>
   <button></button>
 </div>
</a>
```

Here I put a image carousel with dot button in a link tag. Here I face one problem. When I click the card it redirects href link for using a tag. But problem is when I click dot button to slide the images, it ridirect href link. How can I disable href and working dot button for sliding images.

Thank you!

Comment: Move the dot buttons outside the <a>. Button clicks in React are handled by adding `onClick={handlerFunction}` to your buttons.

Comment: Add `onclick={(evt) => evt.stopPropagation()}` on the buttons, [Read Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38619981/how-can-i-prevent-event-bubbling-in-nested-react-components-on-click)

Comment: Basically, it's not a good coding practice to add this much elements under an anchor tag. Second if you wanna avoid redirecting property from certain elements inside the anchor tag, you need to attach a click event to it, handle it, and use `preventDefault()` to stop redirecting. Then you can add redirecting properties to only those elements required.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `onClick` handler function if you want to run some logic like this:

```js
// for functional Components

const handleClick=(e)=>{
     e.preventDefault();
    // write your logic for on click
}
```

```html
 <a onClick={handleClick}>
   <h1>Hello Wolrd</h1>
   <p>This is some description</p>
   <div>....this is Image Carousel</div>
   <div class="dotButton">
     <button></button>
     <button></button>
     <button></button>
   </div>
</a>
```

with this you can do your other stuff on clicking the anchor without redirecting.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this :

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)">
 <h1>Hello Wolrd</h1>
 <p>This is some description</p>
 <div>....this is Image Carousel</div>
 <div class="dotButton">
   <button></button>
   <button></button>
   <button></button>
 </div>
</a>
```

And after that when you will click the image it will not redirect you anymore.